# Draw over something with the pen extension in mit.scratch?

Tags: mit-scratch

I have drawn a picture using the paint feature of scratch and now I want a pen(which I have made through the in-built sprite)to look as if it's drawing over my drawing, I am basically trying to speed draw with my drawing

Comment: Is your drawing a background on the stage, or a costume in a sprite? I assume the latter, otherwise you wouldn't be having this problem. Any reason not to use the background?

Answer (score 1):

The pen draws directly onto the background, it can't draw over any sprites.

Answer (score 1):

If you stamp the sprite onto the canvas, you can draw over it using the pen. Make sure to stamp the sprite down before the pen, otherwise it will stamp over the pen drawing.